# DynamoDB: Query all data and sorted by date descending

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I'm new to the AWS DynamoDB and need a guidance from the experts in here.

I'm creating an application that will display a list of events with a condition the event date must be greater than today date and order by event date descending. My table schema like below:

Partition key = eventid

Sort Key = eventdate

If I use relational db i can use "SELECT * FROM events where eventdate > todaydate ORDERBY eventdate DESC", but how i want to achieve this with AWS DynamoDB? I'm looking to use QUERY instead of SCAN.

Comment: Let's Discuss the same on [Chat Room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138204/chat-between-tj-and-thearrow)

Answer (score 3):

According to [DynamoDB Query API Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) :

> **Query :**
>
> A Query operation uses the primary key of a table or a secondary index
>   to directly access items from that table or index.
>
> Use the **KeyConditionExpression** parameter to provide a specific value
>   for the partition key. The Query operation will return all of the
>   items from the table or index with that partition key value. You can
>   optionally narrow the scope of the Query operation by specifying a
>   **sort key** value and a comparison operator in KeyConditionExpression.
>   **You can use the ScanIndexForward parameter to get results in forward
>   or reverse order, by sort key.**
>
> **KeyConditionExpression** :
>
> The condition that specifies the key value(s) for items to be
>   retrieved by the Query action.
>
> The condition must perform an equality test on a single partition key
>   value. The condition can also perform one of several comparison tests
>   on a single sort key value. Query can use KeyConditionExpression to
>   retrieve one item with a given partition key value and sort key value,
>   or several items that have the same partition key value but different
>   sort key values.
>
> The partition key equality test is required, and must be specified in
>   the following format:
>
> `partitionKeyName = :partitionkeyval`
>
> If you also want to provide a condition for the sort key, it must be
>   combined using AND with the condition for the sort key. Following is
>   an example, using the = comparison operator for the sort key:
>
> `partitionKeyName = :partitionkeyval AND sortKeyName = :sortkeyval`
>
> Valid comparisons for the sort key condition are as follows:
>
> - `sortKeyName = :sortkeyval` - true if the sort key value is equal to :sortkeyval.
> - `sortKeyName < :sortkeyval` - true if the sort key value is less than :sortkeyval.
> - `sortKeyName <= :sortkeyval` - true if the sort key value is less than or equal to :sortkeyval.
> - `sortKeyName > :sortkeyval` - true if the sort key value is greater than :sortkeyval.
> - `sortKeyName >= :sortkeyval` - true if the sort key value is greater than or equal to :sortkeyval.
> - `sortKeyName BETWEEN :sortkeyval1 AND :sortkeyval2` - true if the sort key value is greater than or equal to :sortkeyval1, and less than
>     or equal to :sortkeyval2.
> - `begins_with ( sortKeyName, :sortkeyval )` - true if the sort key value begins with a particular operand. (You cannot use this function
>     with a sort key that is of type Number.)
>
> You can optionally use the ExpressionAttributeNames parameter to
>   replace the names of the partition key and sort key with placeholder
>   tokens. This option might be necessary if an attribute name conflicts
>   with a DynamoDB reserved word. For example, the following
>   KeyConditionExpression parameter causes an error because Size is a
>   reserved word:
>
> ```
> Size = :myval
> ```
>
> To work around this, define a placeholder (such a #S) to represent the
>   attribute name Size. KeyConditionExpression then is as follows:
>
> ```
> #S = :myval
> ```
>
> For a list of reserved words, see Reserved Words in the Amazon
>   DynamoDB Developer Guide.
>
> For more information on ExpressionAttributeNames and
>   ExpressionAttributeValues, see Using Placeholders for Attribute Names
>   and Values in the Amazon DynamoDB Developer Guide.
>
> Type: String
>
> Required: No

**Your Scenario Can be converted to following Code :**

```
$tableName = "genericTable";
$response = $dynamodb->query([
    'TableName' => $tableName,
    'IndexName' => 'OrderCreationDateIndex',
    'KeyConditionExpression' => 'partitionKeyName = :partitionkeyval AND sortKeyName = :sortkeyval',
    'ExpressionAttributeValues' =>  [
        ':partitionkeyval' => ['S' => 'pkey'],
        ':sortkeyval' => ['S' => 'sortkey']
    ],
    'Select' => 'ALL_PROJECTED_ATTRIBUTES',
    'ScanIndexForward' => false,
    'ConsistentRead' => true,
    'Limit' => 5,
    'ReturnConsumedCapacity' => 'TOTAL'
]);
```

Comment: @zalizan-zolkipali, convert Created Date to unixtime and then follow my answer to achieve your task, It's already working & live solution at my end.

Comment: @Zalizan Zolkipali, The above solution would not work as eventId is not part of the query. If eventId is available, it is a straight forward use case for Query API usage.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't achieve the above use case using Query API.

**Reasons:-**

- You need the **greater than comparison operator**. The non-equality comparison operator can be used on `FilterExpression` or on sort key attribute using `KeyConditionExpression`.
- In the above use case, you don't have `eventId`, so you can't use 
  `KeyConditionExpression`. Even if you create a GSI using `eventDate` as hash key, you can't use non-equality operator on hash key and sorting is not possible for any attributes except Sort key. So, you can't achieve the sorting requirement using GSI option.

**Workaround solution to use Query API for above use case:-**

- Create a GSI with hash key as `eventDate`
- Use Query API to query the index by `eventDate`
- Sort the data by `eventDate` at client side. Most of the programming languages has good sorting APIs. You can easily achieve this at client side

**Note:-**

- You can't achieve both sorting and using Query API requirements especially without knowing the hash key of the main table

Comment: Tq for your reply sir. That's mean there is no workaround for me to achieve results as I mentioned in above question?

Comment: @notionquest, Please note that Using Query API, You can use the ScanIndexForward parameter to get results in forward or reverse order, by sort key.

Comment: @LuFFy Here the use case doesn't have the hash key value. OP wanted to use query API without having the hash key value. That's why I proposed to use GSI with hash key as eventDate.

Comment: @notionquest, if OP want to get solution for dynamodb only, then he would have only option to change his table structure and add a SortKey & DONE....He has not posted anything that he is using Hash Key Value, Can you brief me where he said such sentence ?

Comment: @LuFFy, "If I use relational db i can use "SELECT * FROM events where eventdate > todaydate ORDERBY eventdate DESC", but how i want to achieve this with AWS DynamoDB"... Where is the hash key mentioned here. OP wants the equivalent for above query.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since you cannot achieve conditional operator from the hash key in query